# New Badge for consideration

Tags: discussion, badges

The Fanatic (gold) badge is awarded for "Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive days". I believe Web Apps has at least one user who has passed the two year mark and wonder whether additional recognition would be appropriate.

As sites age might consideration be given to a badge of the same kind but with visits measured in years rather than days?

Comment: Did you find anything on MSE about this topic?

Comment: That was fun to read. Those people need counseling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already exists such a badge called [yearling](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=310)

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded **multiple** times.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm convinced the fruitfulness of that badge - might end up with posts of I visited for 364 days, one day I missed yaargh gimme gimme.

(ps: my streak on [su] was 1000+ consecutive days.. no badge for that *sniff*)

Comment: This leaves room for a gold badge, for those who turned up every day.